# Cutting off tetrahedral corners off a cube...

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, problem-solving, 3d, polyhedra

### Problem:

[image]

### Solution:

[image]

The part I don't get is circled in red - why is the side length of the tetrahedron equal to square root 2? If the tetrahedra meet at the midpoints of the cube, then surely the side length of the tetrahedron is equal to 1?

Apologies if I am being obtuse - could someone clarify? Many thanks.

Comment: $S$ is a corner of the cube. The sides with lengths of $1$ are $SP, SQ, SR$. The corner is formed by right angles, so $PQ = QR = PR = \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Ah, okay I see now @player3236 - thanks - does this mean that it isn't necessary for all the edges to be equal for an object to be tetrahedron?

Comment: That would be a *regular* tetrahedron. A tetrahedron is just another name for a pyramid with a triangular base.

Comment: Many thanks @player3236. Much appreciated.